# SQL - How to prevent duplicate in specific condition?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

In general, we can use unique key or primary key to prevent this, but in my case. I am creating an MyFavorite table like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   UserName       |  FavoriteLink                      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   Ryan           |  http://www.google.com             |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   Ryan           |  http://www.yahoo.com              |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   Joyce          |  http://www.google.com             |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   Joyce          |  http://www.cnn.com                |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

So, each user can have a lot of favoritelinks, but they shouldn't have duplicate favoritelink, for example, Ryan shouldn't have two favoritelink for http://www.google.com. but for this table, FavoriteLink field may be duplicate, because both Ryan and Joyce, they all have favoritelink for http://www.google.com.

Here is the question: how can I insert data into this table without duplicate FavoriteLink for specific person?

Comment: You mention unique keys - how are these not suitable in this situation?

Comment: @Will: I guess he didn't know about composite keys, and that making a unique link would mean only one link is admissible (as opposed to unique combo of link+user)

Answer (score 4):

Composite keys.

```
CREATE TABLE userlinks (
  user VARCHAR(255),
  link VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (user, link)
)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE userlinks (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user VARCHAR(255),
  link VARCHAR(255),
  UNIQUE KEY (user, link)
)
```

depending on what exactly it is you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a composite unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username_favorite_uniq ON yourTable (UserName, FavoriteLink)
```